# C++ How to download webpage to string without saving to disk - URLDownloadToFile not work

Tags: c++, string, download, msdn

**How to download webpage into string without saving this page to disk in** **C++**?

[URLDownloadToFile MSDN function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx) only saving page into disk.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look up the other `URLXXX` functions mentioned thereof? How about: [`URLOpenBlockingStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(VS.85).aspx)?

```
//implement filestream that derives from IStream
class StringStream : public IStream
{
  StringStream(std::wstring buf) 
    {
        _refcount = 1;
        _mBuf = buf;
    }

    ~ StringStream ()
    {

    }
   // implement IUknown, IStream interfaces
   private:
    std::wstring _mBuf;
    long _refcount;
 };
```

See the default file based IStream implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752876(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: But how to read that IStream to string? 
I got 



IStream* pStream;
string text;

URLOpenBlockingStream(NULL, "http://www.mysexyserver.com/text.txt", &pStream, 0, NULL);
text = istream2String(pStream);
cout << text << endl;

This not works

Comment: You need to implement your own IStream (it's just an interface) over a string.